# How to use an array with remote variable on remote server in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, ssh, variable-expansion

This is what I am trying to do...

```
#!/bin/bash

array_local=(1 2 3 4 5)

ssh user@server << EOF
index_remote=1
echo \$index_remote
echo \${array_local[\$index_remote]}  
EOF
```

When I try to run the above script I get the O/P as 1 and a null value (blank space). I wanted ${array_local[$index_remote} value to be 2 instead of null, I need to access this local array using remote variable for my further work in the script..

Comment: What shell are you using? bash?

Comment: What makes you think that a variable (`array_local`) defined on your local system will be magically pre-defined for you in a different shell session in a completely separate process running on a remote server? That variable is local to the shell that runs `ssh`, and, even if you figure out the proper quoting to use, it is not set in the shell instance that runs `echo`...

Comment: @AdamSpiers Yes, it is a bash shell

Comment: @twalberg yes the variable array_local is defined locally, but I can access the variable within the remoter server, I have confirmed this by giving an echo ${array_local[*]}  in the remote server process, it does print the array..the question is how do I now access the array with the remote variable, which is local to the remote server..

Comment: @user2928822 I think you misunderstood the results of `${array_local[*]}`. The way you are running that, it is expanded on the local end, before it is passed to the remote server. What the remote server sees is `echo 1 2 3 4 5`. The local variable is not available on the remote end.

Comment: @twalberg ok, I am quite new to these concepts, as you said the variable is getting expanded at the local end, just as I give ${array_local[<index>]}, I want that index to be taken from the remote server variable..is this possible in any way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<EOF` results variable expansion happening on the local machine, but you only defined the variable `i` on the remote machine.  You need to think carefully about where you want to do the expansion.  You haven't explained in your question whether the value of `i` is defined client-side or server-side, but I'm guessing from your subsequent comments that you want it done server-side.  In that case you'll need to pass the array contents over `ssh`, which requires careful quoting:

```
ssh hostname@server <<EOF
i=1
eval `typeset -p array_local`
echo \${array_local[\$i]}
EOF
```

`typeset -p array_local` will output the string

```
declare -a array_local='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5")'
```

Since this is inside backticks, it will get expanded client-side within the `EOF`-delimited heredoc, and then evaluated server-side by the `eval`.  In other words it's equivalent to:

```
ssh hostname@server <<'EOF'
i=1
declare -a array_local='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5")'
echo ${array_local[$i]}
EOF
```

Notice the difference in `EOF` quoting between the two examples.  The first one allows parameter and shell expansion, and the second doesn't.  That's why the `echo` line in the first one needs quoting, to ensure that parameter expansion happens server-side not client-side.

Comment: I understand that, but I can't figure out any way around, I have tried using 'EOF', that makes my array_local null as obvious, I am looking for a way in which I can access both my local as well as remoter variable within a command..is it just my fiction to think so or is it really possible??

Comment: It's absolutely possible (and not even hard) but you still haven't clearly described what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've guessed what you are asking for and expanded my answer.

Comment: I have edited my question, I have tried with \${array_local[\$i]}, it still gives me a null value...!!

Comment: Read my answer again. The typeset part is not optional.  Also reread twalberg's first comment. It seems that you are still not thinking clearly about what gets expanded when.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) figured it out with your help, now able to run my script perfectly, thank you...!!