# Iterate over array by index over SSH

Tags: bash, for-loop, ssh

For the following code:

```sh
array1=( "Germany" "Vietnam" "Argentina" )
array2=( "Europe" "Asia" "America" )
       
sshpass -p $IPA_PASS ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $IPA_NAME@$TARGET "sudo su - jboss <<'EOF'
for i in "${!array1[@]}"
do
    echo \$i
    echo \${array1[\$i]} "is in" \${array2[\$i]}
done
EOF
"
```

I want the output:

> 0 
> Germany is in Europe
> 1 
> Vietnam is in Asia
> 2 
> Argentia is in America

But I get:

> 0
> Germany is in Europe
> 1
> Germany is in Europe
> 2
> Germany is in Europe

So the index is printed correctly but the value taken from the array over SSH is always the first element. How can this be respectively the first, second, and third element?

The for-loop works fine when not passed over SSH in EOF statements, but the script needs to be run over SSH.

Comment: The double quote preceding `sudo` is matched by the first double quote in the line `for i in "${!array1[@]}"`.

Comment: `array1` and `array2` are only defined locally.  You cannot iterate over their values on the remote.  The iteration will need to take place where the arrays are defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transfer the definitions of two arrays using `declare -p` :

```
array1=( "Germany" "Vietnam" "Argentina" )
array2=( "Europe" "Asia" "America" )

sshpass -p $IPA_PASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $IPA_NAME@$TARGET sudo -u jboss bash\
    < <(declare -p array1 array2; cat <<'EOF'
        for i in "${!array1[@]}"
        do
            echo $i
            echo ${array1[i]} "is in" ${array2[i]}
        done
EOF
        )
```

Comment: Thanks. This pointed in the right direction. Although I had some problems with making the above work as is, I managed to transfer the definitions using `eval \`typeset -p array1\`` as described ["How to use an array with remote variable on remote server in shell scripting?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640235/3162394).

Comment: If you fill in the three variables : $IPA_PASS, $IPA_NAME, $TARGET, my solution should work. What problem have you got ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example with bash for local testing. You can exchange the two bash commands by ssh / sudo:

```
bash -c "bash <<EOF
array1=( \"Germany\" \"Vietnam\" \"Argentina\" )
array2=( \"Europe\" \"Asia\" \"America\" )
for i in \\\${!array1[@]}
do
echo \\\$i
echo \\\${array1[\\\$i]} is in \\\${array2[\\\$i]}
done
EOF
"
```

You also might think about transferring a working script to your remote machine and execute it there in order to escape the quoting-madness.

Comment: Write the bash script in a file and show how to run it rather than adding the entire script in command line - this will render the solution highly unreadable.

/*STEP 1: create file as below*/
 % cat bash
#!/bin/bash
array1=("Germany" "Vietnam" "Argentina" )
array2=( "Europe" "Asia" "America" )
for i in ${!array1[@]}
do
echo $i
echo ${array1[$i]} is in ${array2[$i]}
done

/* STEP 2: Run the file as below *?
% bash ./bash
0
Germany is in Europe
1
Vietnam is in Asia
2
Argentina is in America
 %

Comment: I think this would work but decided to use the approach with transferring variables described in the answer above.

Comment: Sure! I like it, too ;-)